Can I control IR filter of night vision camera
I'm using night vision camera (PIS-1138) with Raspberry Pi 4 and Picamera2 Python3 library successfully.
However, the camera seems to switch some sort of IR filter automatically on/off based on the daylight condition. This has worked nicely so far, that it switches the filter on during the night and produces the blue image below.

But now, unexpectedly, it seems that the switch is not turning on, and the camera produces the red image.

It's still a night vision image I think, cause there's only IR light available for the camera. I'm generally confused why there's a blue image and a red image, as I've only thought there's night vision and normal vision.
I wonder what's going on? Can I control this somehow via Python3, to also confirm if the switch is broken or something?
Unfortunately it seems there's very limited documentation available about this camera module.

Is there a reason why you've not gone to your vendor and requested documentation for the camera?

I have asked the vendor, and there's no more documentation available than a datasheet, which doesn't explain functionality.

No documentation? In that case, you should return it for a refund.

The "red" image is a lot clearer than the blue image, and it's actually magenta/purple, ie., red + blue.  I would guess it is doing some colour adjustment and was not getting it right before for some reason (cut out all the red).  I'd even bet if you put it in an image editor and filter the red out, you'll end up with the (much darker) blue image, but you will never be able to get the purple image from the blue original.

This camera has no IR Filter. A regular Daylight Camera has an IR Filter to stop IR Light coming to the Sensor. When you build a nightvision, you have to remove this filter (this is done for you by the manufacturer) and add an IR Light Source to your Camera. The reflected IR Light can now be recognized by your Camera Sensor. You could also use regular visible Light, but when you try to take a look on animals, they would be frigthened by the light, so you use a light, which they can't see. So there is no possibility to "adjust" the filter. He is either installed, or not.
The IR Leds you have installed (the two cylinders on the outer side) have a lot of Power. You could check if they are working properly when you make a video with a Smartphone Cam of your Raspi Cam at night. You should be able to see, if the LEDs are shining. Test this with your IR Remote of your TV when you Switch your Smartphone to Camera Mode, go to the Live view in picture mode, point to the TV remote and press a button. You should see the Led of the remote shining on the display but not with your regular sight.
Then check your Raspi Cam Leds. Maybe they become to hot, or your Power Supply has not enough power.
